# Formula Needed: How to calculate Time Escaped

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

We have an escape room business. We're trying to get a leaderboard setup but we can't seem to figure out how to set the times in excel. Can someone please help?

*Format is (minutes:seconds)*

A 35:06

B 24:54

---

A = Time Left on the clock

B = Time Escaped the Room

---

Now my question is, what formula should I use to get the time escaped(B)?

Comment: `=time(1,0,0) - A1`?

Answer (score 0):

When entering times, follow the format hh:mm:ss, which means in particular that if a time interval is less than one hour, you must put 0 first (e.g. 0:35:06 or 0:24:54). Then you can add or subtract them as you wish.

Comment: I figured that we had to do something like this. We would have to retrain the whole staff to do it in order for them to get it. Thank you.